# Using DLLImport with an output char[] containing null characters

Tags: c#, .net, interop

I am writing a c# app using .NET 2.0. I need to use an old library for proprietary compression. I don't have source code for the library, and the developers behind it are long gone.

My problem is that the resulting char[] contains nulls, and is being truncated. Here is the declaration for the function:

```
[DLLImport("foo.dll")]
public static extern bool CompressString(char[] inputValue, out char[] outputValue, uint inputLength, out uint outputLength);
```

How can I declare that the output char[] should be handled as a byte[], and not null terminated?

---

More info:

I do have the header file. Here is the declaration:

```
BOOL CompressString(char *DecompBuff, char **RetBuff, unsigned long DecompLen, unsigned long *RetCompLen);
```

Comment: Don't you have the header file that declares the `CompressString` function or at least some documentation describing the arguments of the function? How do you know the signature?

Comment: You shouldn't use `char` in your C# code anywhere, but `byte` or `sbyte` (which is equivalent to C++ `char`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6.aspx) for passing arrays in P/Invoke. I think that you may want to use the `SizeParamIndex` to tell the marshaller which argument holds the size of the array passed along.

Edit: `SizeParamIndex` is unfortunately not allowed on `out` and `ref` parameters. You could, however, copy it manually:

```
[DLLImport("foo.dll")]
public static extern bool CompressString([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=2)] char[] inputValue, out IntPtr outputValue, uint inputLength, out uint outputLength);

public static bool CompressStringInvoke(char[] inputValue, out char[] outputValue, uint inputLength) {
    IntPtr outputPtr;
    uint outputLen;
    if (CompressString(inputValue, out outputPtr, inputLength, out outputLen)) {
        outputValue = new char[outputLen];
        Marshal.Copy(outputPtr, outputValue, 0, (int)outputLen);
        return true;
    }
              outputValue = new char[0];
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I get this error: Cannot marshal 'parameter #2': Cannot use SizeParamIndex for ByRef array parameters.

Comment: Right. Edited with an alternate solution.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! (I fixed a couple of minor syntax issues)

Comment: `Marshal.Copy` will copy bytes, not chars. In general, it seems that this needs `byte` everywhere there is `char` currently.

Comment: @Jon: thanks!
@Pavel: no, it's the number of elements according to the documentation. Since this uses the `char[]` overload, that should be fine, if the C-char is 16-bit.

Answer (score 0):

[Pinvoke.Net](http://www.pinvoke.net) should provide you some hints on declaring your method signature